Extracting Components of a Defined Coordinate
I would like to extract the x/y components of a predefined coordinate. Currently, I am able to do this using the following methods:
\coordinate (a) at (3, 2);

% Method 1
\path (a);
\pgfgetlastxy\x\y

% Method 2
\path (a);
\pgf@x\pgf@y

However, both of these methods require something like \path (a); to be executed. I am curious if there is a macro or internal mechanism that stores the components directly when the \coordinate command is used, for example:
\coordinate (a) at (3, 2);

% Hypothetical example
\pgf@coordinate@a@x=3cm
\pgf@coordinate@a@y=2cm


I want to know if pgf assigns a corresponding macro to each coordinate to save their missing coordinates.

\coordinate is just \path coordinate inside a tikzpicture. if you use \pgfpoint you can inspect the internal registers which hold the components \pgf@x and \pgf@y. but these are scoped in high-level commands like \coordinate so they aren't accessible after the end of the group. that is, \coordinate etc. are all going to be using the pgf stuff so the internal registers will get set, but you can't get the values back from \pgf@x if you use the higher-level wrappers. (at least, I don't think so.) and you haven't (1) provided complete code or (2) explained what you want this for.

so it is quite unclear whether a lower-level solution might be an option or if some other approach might avoid the problem altogether.

No, PGF doesn't assign a macro for each part (x, y) of a coordinate. For every node (and a coordinate is a node), five macros are globally saved: these hold the shape's name, a picture ID, saved points, saved macros and a transformation matrix. The last one is used by PGF to locate a coordinate later, basically when \pgfpointanchor is used. This is the lowest user-level macro but it will return the coordinates in \pgf@x and \pgf@y.

The calc library provides let \p0=(…) in on a path which makes \x0 and \y0 available for use. The math library can do coordinate \c; \c=(…); which makes \cx and \cy available. What do you want to do with these values? What do you need them for?

I found a way that seems to avoid using \path, but it doesn't completely solve my problem. I'll record it here and I will continue to update it later.
\coordinate (ljguo) at (1,5);
\pgfpointanchor{ljguo}{center}
\the\pgf@x, \the\pgf@y

